# Regex only capture first match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to parse a string using regex, example of the string is

`Lot: He said: Thou shalt not pass!`

I want to capture `Lot` as a group, and `He said: Thou shalt not pass!`. However, when I used my `(.+): (.+)` pattern, it returns

`Lot: He said:` and `Thou shalt not pass!`

Is it possible to capture `He said: Thou shalt not pass` using regex?

Comment: do you want to capture the second part without `!`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need a non-greedy (or lazy) cardinality for the first group: `(.+?): (.+)`.

More details on http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html, chapter "Laziness Instead of Greediness".

Comment: Works like a charm, @sp00m sorry for not able to upvote because my lack of reps.

Answer (score 5):

give this a try:

```
([^:]+):\s*(.*)
```

Comment: +1 for using negative character class rather than `.`

Comment: @funkwurm negative character class is considered faster than non-greedy matching.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?=.*?:.*?:)(.*?):(.*)
```

You can use this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rX0dM7/9

Answer (score 2):

You should use the flags ig - i = case insensitive, g = don't return after first match and a expression like "(.*:) ?(.*: .*)".

You can see example here
https://regex101.com/r/SXjg1b/1

Answer (score 0):

The following one works.

`([^:]+): (.+)`

Comment: Could you please explain it in more details?

Comment: please see the following link for explanation [link](http://regex101.com/r/jE3jU8/1)